# Wood Splitting By hitting object

Tags: animation

How can i animate a wood splitting into 2 parts? Just like by hitting some axes.
I tried rigging and also Boolean modifier ,but it did work as i want.In rendering ,It show that they already are separate objects.

Answer (score -1):

I didn't try that, but I think you can use use a complete version of the wood object and when the axe hit it, hide it (by a keyframe) and show that splitted one.

Comment: Any reason why -1?

Comment: Thank...But i want to show a gradual split........

Comment: i was just by mistake